# Accessing plugins in jenkins shared library classes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I wanted to create a class in `/src` directory which can access docker and other plugin steps.

So I have a class that looks like this;

```groovy
class someClassName implements Serializable {
    def env
    def steps
    def docker

    someclassName(env, steps, docker){
        this.step = step
        this.docker = docker
        this.env = env
    }

    def runCommands(String img, List commands){
       docker.image(img).inside {
           commands.each {
             steps.sh it
           }
       }
    }
```

Now in `Jenkinsfile` I will have

```groovy
@Library('name@branch') _
def x = new com.JenkinsLibrary.someClassName(env, steps, docker)
x.runCommands('maven:latest', ['mvn clean', 'mvn test'])
```

What i dont like is how I have a constructor for each object so that I can call methods that belong to that object. Is there a better object that i can use for my constructor instead of having to use env, steps, docker, etc?

Also, what pipeline steps are available under steps object? same for env?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending along the surrounding `CPSScript`:

```groovy
class someClassName implements Serializable {
    def script

    someclassName(script){
        this.script = script
    }

    def runCommands(String img, List commands){
        script.docker.image(img).inside {
            commands.each {
                script.sh it
           }
       }
    }
}
```

and you provide the script by using `this` in the pipeline script:

```groovy
@Library('name@branch') _
def x = new com.JenkinsLibrary.someClassName(this)
x.runCommands('maven:latest', ['mvn clean', 'mvn test'])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. To extend on this, is it also possible to use script for all other pipeline steps?  Would i be able to use script for most of the objects from pipeline snippet generator? for ex; script.sh, script.httpRequest, script.readJSON in classes under `/src` dir

Comment: Yes, that should work... I haven't run into any limitations yet. Just be ware that you can't use the script variable inside methods annotated with `@NonCPS`...

Comment: but it should work on classes that implement Serializable correct? and yes this is great!  Thank you so much!!!